# Youtube not blocked by iptables

Tags: iptables

On our Ubuntu machine I have attempted to block internet access to one of the user accounts by adding the following line to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
pre-up iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j DROP
```

This works well except somehow Youtube and other Google properties are not blocked.

I'm not an expert in iptables, but I assumed the above command would drop *all* outgoing requests from the specified user. Is there something special about Google properties that would somehow cause them to be exempted?

For reference here is my iptables list:

```
$ sudo iptables --list

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             owner UID match ****
```

Comment: This can easily be circumvented by tunneling TCP over another protocol, BTW.

Comment: Is there any chance your Internet connection is IPv6 enabled? That would not be blocked by an iptables rule.

Comment: Note that this will soon start applying to *many* more sites, not just Google and YouTube. Today Cloudflare announced that they have support for HTTP/3, Mozilla announced that Firefox will have support very soon, and it's only a matter of time before lots of other join in. HTTP/3 is based on Google's QUIC protocol and also runs over UDP, so it has the same issue.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Is the user using Chrome/Chromium? If so, the browser is most likely using [QUIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC) for those sites, and that protocol uses UDP as the transport.

You can block UDP ports 80 and 443 to solve it.

Comment: You can also just remove `-p tcp` and thereby block everything.

Comment: I wondered if there was something special about Chrome with Google sites. That was definitely it. I removed -p tcp and everything is now blocked.